$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k k$ is $(C,2)$ summable to $-\frac{1}{4}$
I am trying to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k k = -\frac{1}{4}\quad (C,2)$$
First I look at the partial sums:
$S_1 = -1$, $S_2 = 1$, $S_3 = -2$, $S_4 = 2$...
These will diverge to $\pm\infty$ so the series is not $(C,1)$. Now consider $\sigma_i$
$\sigma_1 = -1$, $\sigma_2 = 0$, $\sigma_3 = -\frac{2}{3}$, $\sigma_4 = 0$...
We notice that the even terms are zero. Now consider $\tau_n$ to be the sequence converging to the $(C,2)$ limit.
$\tau_1 = -1$, $\tau_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$, $\tau_3 = -\frac{-5}{9}$,$\tau_4 = -\frac{-5}{12}$...
We can notice that by removing the odd terms we get rid of the occasionally decreasing terms, which occur due to the zeroes from $\sigma$'s. Now we have an increasing "subsequence" which is bounded by $0$ and thus must converge. But I am unsure how to show the exact limit.. Any hints?:) thanks!

The primary difficulty you're having is you aren't writing out explicitly the formulas for the terms.
We start with:
$S_1 = -1, S_2 = 1, S_3 = -2, .... $
Thus if $n$ is odd,
$$ S_n = - \frac{(n+1)}{2}  $$
And if $n$ is even
$$ S_n =  \frac{n}{2} $$
Now we go ahead and create a formula for $\sigma_n$
$$ \sigma_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} S_n}{n} $$
First we need to handle the inner sum which we call as $p_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} S_n$.
$$ p_1 = -1, p_2 = 0, p_3 = -2, p_4 = 0, ... $$
Therefore $p_n = -\frac{(n+1)}{2}$ if $n$ is odd and 0 otherwise. Therefore
$$ \sigma_n = -\frac{(n+1)}{2n} $$
if n is odd and $0$ otherwise.
Now we consider $\tau_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_n }{n} $
At this point we can, bash out one more formula but that might be effortful. Instead we consider $\sigma_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. From Calculus we know:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} - \frac{(n+1)}{2n} = -\frac{1}{2} $$
So if $n$ is odd the terms are getting increasingly close to $-\frac{1}{2}$.
On the other hand if $n$ is even the terms are just $0$.
So the average $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \tau_n$ consists of averaging $-\frac{1}{2}$ with $0$ giving us the famed $-\frac{1}{4}$ result.
Again, notice that we can't do this limit intellectual gymnastics UNTIL we have explicit formulas to work with. Once you start going deep into divergent series you need to be very concrete about your sums and sequences. You can "think" in terms of sequences like $-1, 2, -3, 4 ... $ but once you get to work there need to be explicit formulas with explicit bounds (the difference between $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1 = -\frac{1}{2}$ vs $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1 = \frac{1}{2}$ for example. Both are written as
$1+1+1+...$ but those sums are NOT the same!).

I understand. I was only introduced to this summation today as a preposition to the Fourier series. In class, we had some easier examples where when you write out a few terms you notice a general formula. I was expecting the same to pop up here for the $\tau_n$. I was expecting a hint :) but now that you solved it why can you take that average at the end?

Great question! so $\tau_n$ is an average of $\sigma_1 ... \sigma_n$. Lets consider only odd numbers for now. What does it mean for $\sigma_n$ to converge to $c$ when $n$ is odd? It means that for any $e >0$ (say 0.05 for 5%, which is pretty close) there is some $M$ s.t. for ANY $d > M$ $|\sigma_d - c| < e$ or concretely $|\sigma_d - (-\frac{1}{2})| < 0.05$. Lets think about this carefully...

... you declare a magic number like 5%. There are INFINITELY many $\sigma_n$ that are within 5% of $-\frac{1}{2}$ but there are only FINITELY many $\sigma_n$ that are more than 5% away. If we average infinitely many things that are within 5% with FINITELY many things that are NOT within 5% our conclusion is that our limit is STILL within 5%. But it need not have been 5%. You could've said 0.1% or 0.01% or 0.001% and it would still be true that there are INFINITELY many $\sigma_n$ that are that close (or closer) but only FINITELY many that are NOT that close.

So when we evaluate $\tau_n$ by averaging $\sigma_n$ initially we are averaging crazy numbers like $-1, 0, -\frac{2}{3}, 0, -\frac{3}{5}... $ but eventually our list is going to look like $... -\frac{1}{2}, 0, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, .... $. It will never be EXACTLY that but for any error $e>0$ there is a finite $N$ afterwhich for INFINITELY many element the list looks like  $... -\frac{1}{2} + \text{Error < e}, 0, -\frac{1}{2} + \text{Error < e}, 0, ... $. And we are FREE to let that error be as SMALL as we like, so we might as well just let the Error go to 0

Said in more casual terms: if you gaze towards n=infinity the $\sigma_n$ list looks like $-\frac{1}{2}, 0, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, -\frac{1}{2}, 0 ... $ And the further you gaze out, the CLOSER it looks like that list. And limit $\tau_n$ takes the ENTIRE LIST (all infinitely many terms of it) so you conclude that to compute the LIMIT of $\tau_n$ you only need to consider the LIMIT of $\sigma_n$ (so we average them)

ah. Yes. Very clear now, thank you :)

Feel free to comment further if anything becomes unclear after later inspection :)
